# Magento 2.4.3-p1, order out-of-stock product in list.phtml

Tags: magento2, list.phtml, magento2.4.3.p1

I need to apply out-of-stock products at the end of the page.

How to set an order?

->add Attribute To Sort('is_in_stock', 'DESC')

or

->order('is_in_stock DESC')

DIR:
MAGENTO\app\design\frontend\BASE\THEME\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this in your list.phtml

```
<?php
$currentCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$inStockProducts = [];
$outOfStockProducts = [];

foreach ($currentCollection as $product) {
    if ($product->isSaleable()) {
        $inStockProducts[] = $product;
    } else {
        $outOfStockProducts[] = $product;
    }
}

// Merge the arrays to put out-of-stock products at the end
$sortedProducts = array_merge($inStockProducts, $outOfStockProducts);
?>

<!-- Rest of your list.phtml file content -->

<?php foreach ($sortedProducts as $_product) : ?>
    <!-- Your product listing code here -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked, thank you.

Comment: When there is pagination, out of stock products are not on the last page, is there another way to fix this?